# Parsing datetime with milliseconds

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, date, datetime

stackoverflow community. I was writing a program which takes a data from optical unit and stores to the server. I am having a problem with parsing the data with pandas. In my data, the datetimes are with milliseconds. However, I dont know how to parse a date with corresponding format string. My code is only converting string into year,month,day,hour,minute, and second. My code:

```
data['Datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(data['Datetime'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

This is the sample datetime from
the source I am using: **2021-07-09 09:41:30.839000**
Thanks for any help)

Comment: Can't reproduce. The code works for sample date. Most likely your data is having 0:s in the column. You can either filter or add error-handling: format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f', errors = 'coerce' )

Comment: you can set `errors='coerce'` to leave nonconvertible elements as `NaT` and suppress the error.

Answer (score 0):

try without passing the format:

```
pd.to_datetime("2021-07-09 09:41:30.839000")
```

> Timestamp('2021-07-09 09:41:30.839000')